# Protractor : WebDriverError: unknown error: operation is unsupported on Android

Tags: android, protractor, appium

I am trying to run protractor tests on real device (Android Phone, Android 5.0.1 version). It is opening the browser (Chrome) but not navigating to the url and throwing below error message.

```
super(opt_error);
         ^
WebDriverError: unknown error: operation is unsupported on Android
  (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.105)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64).
```

Here is code from conf js ( pasing only required code ):

```
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',

   capabilities: {
     browserName: 'chrome',
     platformName: 'android',
     deviceName: ' ',
   },
   framework: 'jasmine2',
   specs: ['../functional/AppLogin.js'],
```

Actual Spec code:

```
describe("Verify Login", function(){
     it("Verify Application Login",function(){
         browser.get("http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/");
     });
});
```

Note: Device connected to system properly, Appium node server running fine.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and the problem was that I was trying to set the window size of the browser, and this cannot be done when running on a real device. This was the line which was causing the issue:

```
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(400, 800);
```

Comment: Hi @dwane_d Were u able to use some alternative to .driver.manage().window().setSize() on Appium?

Comment: @san1deep2set3hi I think that because of changing the window size of the browser is not supported in this case, then there isn't an alternative.